# Copy cell contents based on duplicates

Tags: scripting

For my student caseload spreadsheet, I need a script to search the sheet when there is a new entry for a duplicate (pre-existing) first and last name (columns B and C) and copy the link in column K to column K of the new entry. Help?

Thanks,!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You forgot to mention (a) what spreadsheet program you are using, (b) what scripting language (use the tags), and (c) what you already tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Oops. Sorry! Teachers are submitting students via Google Forms to my Google Sheet. I want to use the Google Script editor to automate this. I had been using Form Publisher to link to the entry, but it creates a new doc for every new entry, even if the student already exists on the sheet.This is actually one piece of a larger script I'm trying to create.

Comment: Here's the full functionality I'm looking for:  On new entry, check to see if there is a previous entry for that student (column B and C). If so, copy the link to the Google Doc that was generated with a template to the new row (column K). If not, create a new doc from the new entry and and link it to the row K.

Comment: If anyone out there can provide the code to a part of this, I think I can stitch it together.